# How to force plotly plots to correct starting point on x axis?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I'm plotting the sales numbers (`amount`) per week `YYYYWW` per product `product_name`.

All the data appears on the graph, however some of the products are showing incorrectly. If product A only started having sales figures from year 2019 (ie no sales figures for the whole of 2018); then I want the line for that product to be zero in 2018 and begin showing values from 2019.

What's happening instead is Product A is showing the line graph from the origin of the graph. So week 1 of sales is at `YYYYWW` 201801 instead.

Is there a more efficient way to solve this than to place zero values for the product with a list comprehension?

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo

data = [go.Scatter(x=sorted(df.YYYYWW.unique().astype(str)), 
                   y=list(df.loc[df.product_name == 'Product A', 
                       ['amount','YYYYWW']].groupby('YYYYWW').sum().amount),
                   mode='lines+markers',
                  )
        ]

pyo.plot(data)
```

[image]

The values in x are: 201801, 201802, ... 201920

The values in y are:

```
YYYYWW     amount

2019/15     454.32
2019/16    1131.15
2019/17    1152.96
2019/18    2822.77
2019/19    3580.86
2019/20    2265.06
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it!
My x values should be taken from a subset of the dataframe just as done in my y values:

```
x = df.loc[df.product_name == i].YYYYWW.unique().astype(str)
```